# Sort dates in mm/dd/yy and dd/mm/yy where I know the month they are from

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of date **strings** I know are from a single month, in this case the dates are all between January and February 2020. I want to sort them in ascending order. However, they are in different formats some in mm/dd/yy, some in dd/mm/yy. How can I sort them?

```py
data = {
    'date': ['1/1/2020','20/1/2020', '1/1/2020', '1/28/2020','21/1/2020', '1/25/2020', '29/1/2020'],
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Edit

Another sample of dates I'd like to be sorted

---

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Tgl': {
  1: '1/1/2023',
  2: '1/1/2023',
  3: '1/3/2023',
  4: '1/5/2023',
  5: '1/5/2023',
  6: '1/9/2023',
  7: '10/1/2023',
  8: '12/1/2023',
  9: '16/1/2023'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = pd.to_datetime(df['Tgl'])

df = pd.to_datetime(df['Tgl'], dayfirst = True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the provided example, there is limited ambiguity as you don't have cases for which a day ≤ 12 is different from the month.

So you can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)(`pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`) to convert to a clean datetime, or, to sort while keeping the original strings:

```
df.sort_values(by='date', key=pd.to_datetime)
```

Output:

```
       date
0   1/1/2020
2   1/1/2020
1  20/1/2020
4  21/1/2020
5  1/25/2020
3  1/28/2020
6  29/1/2020
```

If you have ambiguous dates (like `1/2/2020`) you can choose to give priority to days/months with the `dayfirst` parameter:

```
df.sort_values(by='date', key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, dayfirst=True))
```

Example:

```
        date
2   2/1/2020  # Jan 2nd
1  20/1/2020
4  21/1/2020
5  1/25/2020
3  1/28/2020
6  29/1/2020
0   1/2/2020  # Feb 1st
```

##### custom logic

Let's assume the first number is the day, unless the value is > 2, in which case we convert it to month.

```
def custom_date(s):
    return (
      pd.to_datetime(s, dayfirst=True)
        .mask(lambda x: x.dt.month>2,
              pd.to_datetime(s, dayfirst=False))
    )

df.sort_values(by='date', key=custom_date)
```

Output (with an additional column to see the result of the custom conversion):

```
        date  converted
2   2/1/2020 2020-01-02
7  10/1/2020 2020-01-10 # both converted 
8  1/10/2020 2020-01-10 # to Jan 10
1  20/1/2020 2020-01-20
4  21/1/2020 2020-01-21
5  1/25/2020 2020-01-25
3  1/28/2020 2020-01-28
6  29/1/2020 2020-01-29
0   1/2/2020 2020-02-01
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what would you do if there was more ambiguity with the dates, where some of the days are <= 12 e.g. 10/1/2020 and 11/1/2020

Comment: @Meg have you checked the second part of my answer? I'm covering this case with `dayfirst`. Let me know if you have specific questions.

Comment: It's almost always a good idea to convert date strings to `datetime` dtype before trying to do anything serious with the data.

Comment: I added another logic if you want to try to force the month to always be ≤ 2. And I can only agree with @shadowtalker! Use `datetime` whenever possible (using an extra column if you want to keep the original string)

Comment: @mozway I've just added an edit to my question with a new dataset. doing a clean `.to_datetime()` doesnt work since the `10/1/2023` and `12/1/2023` turn into October and December 1st, and doing `dayfirst = True` doesnt work since the dates that start with `1/../2023` get treated as the 1st of whatever month

Comment: See my lastest update ;)

Comment: @mozway Really appreciate it...sorry for asking so much but is it also possible to make the final result all datetime objects formatted in dd/mm/yy? So that if I do 
`df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day`, it'll give me the day for each datetime? Ill give you mark your answer as accepted regardless

Comment: Yes: `custom_date(df['date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` for a string, else just `custom_date(df['date'])` (much better, but visually formatted as yyyy-mm-dd). A combination is unfortunately not possible